# Merge two or more resultsets to a formatted JSON format

Tags: java, json, dataset, resultset, virtuoso

I am running a query that outputs some JSON results retrieved from RDF graphs. Results are printed as:

```
{
  "head": {
     "vars": [ "uri" , "label" ]
       } ,
     "results": {
      "bindings": [                      {
            "uri": { "type": "uri" , "value": "Some value" } ,
    "label": { "type": "literal" , "xml:lang": "en" , "value": "biomass" }
  }
]
 }
 }

{
  "head": {
     "vars": [ "uri" , "label" ]
          } ,
     "results": {
        "bindings": [
            {
              "uri": { "type": "uri" , "value": "some value" } ,
              "label": { "type": "literal" , "xml:lang": "en" , "value": "biomass" }
                        }
                    ]
           }
 }
```

What I would like to do is to merge both results into one with different URIs and labels. This is the code I use to get the results:

```
        VirtuosoQueryExecution vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create (
        text, set);

    ResultSet results = vqe.execSelect();
    /*while(results.hasNext()){
        QuerySolution result = results.nextSolution();
        RDFNode node = result.get("uri");
        test += "\ntest:  "+ node +"  \n";
    }*/
    ResultSetFormatter.outputAsJSON(out, results);
    }
    return out.toString();
    //return test;
```

I use the commented part to get only the URIs displayed, but that is not really what is needed! I need the whole result set, but merged. Like the following :

```
{

 "head": {

"vars": [ "uri" , "label" ]

  } ,
    "results": {

    "bindings": [

  {
    "uri": { "type": "uri" , "value": "Some value" } ,

    "label": { "type": "literal" , "xml:lang": "en" , "value": "biomass" }   

    "uri": { "type": "uri" , "value": "Some other value" } ,

    "label": { "type": "literal" , "xml:lang": "en" , "value": "biomass" }

  }

]

  }

}
```

Comment: Please add the desired output format based on the examples above.

Comment: @Smutje I just did! thanks

Comment: You can't have two nodes with same name at same level.

Comment: @RahulBobhate the name was just arbitrary! it could be anything!